# Why does my code give an error before it's finished in PyCharm

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I am running PyCharm 64bit on my PC (iCore 7 and 16 G gb ram).

The code is a loop and processes the same data, but changing one variable that influences the output.

The code takes about 40 min to cycle through different values for the same variable. I get the error (pasted below) after about 12 minutes.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

I've tried setting Xms and Xmx for larger memory, restarting, and I still get the error.
I tried running the code on two other computers (one Mac and one PC) - it works on other computers.
I've tried running Anaconda Navigator and using a notebook, and this works.

The error I get is as follows:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
  File "C:\Users\Mark\VineLifeCode\App.py", line 192, in run
    process_tree(tree_file, data_path, Save_path, deps, dthetas, epss, nf, nspans, res)
  File "C:\Users\Mark\VineLifeCode\App.py", line 258, in process_tree
    pd.DataFrame(df_path).to_excel(writer_path, sheet_name=sheet_name)
  File "C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\Tree_code (IDE)\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2127, in to_excel
  File "C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\Tree_code (IDE)\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\excel.py", line 662, in write
  File "C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\Tree_code (IDE)\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 1993, in write_cells
  File "C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\Tree_code (IDE)\venv\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\worksheet.py", line 69, in cell_wrapper
  File "C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\Tree_code (IDE)\venv\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\worksheet.py", line 411, in write
  File "C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\Tree_code (IDE)\venv\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\worksheet.py", line 433, in _write
  File "C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\Tree_code (IDE)\venv\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\worksheet.py", line 577, in _write_number
MemoryError
```

Comment: Show the code as well.

Comment: Did you check the memory usage, for example by looking at the task manager? What does it looks like? How much memory does it take?

Comment: @DanielNudelman
Memory use is very low - around 28% of RAM and about 17% of processor.